# Disable copy/assignment, automatically disabled for children?

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

When using the following code to disable copy and assignment:

```
Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
```

Will this also automatically disable copy and assigment of child classes of Foo?

```
class Bar : public Foo {
}
```

Or, in other words, can `Bar` be copied?

Comment: No, `Bar` can't be copied.

Comment: How can `Bar` be copied when one of its components is non-copyable?

Comment: Thanks for the answers! If you put it into an answer, I can accept :)

Comment: That automatically disables the default copy and assignment of child classes of `Foo`.  It does not prevent someone writing a child class of `Foo` from writing their own copy constructor and/or assignment operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this also inhibits implicit copying of child classes. In fact that's how inheriting from `boost::noncopyable` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/core/doc/html/core/noncopyable.html) works. However someone could always write their own copy constructor/copy assignment for the child class that doesn't actually copy the `Foo` component, or copies it in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

behavior of "delete" is similar to "boost::noncopyable" .In c++11 , compiler is doing the task for you .

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Car {
public:
  Car(const Car&) = delete;
  void operator=(const Car&) = delete;
  Car(): owner(0) {}
  void setOwner() { owner = 0; }

private:
 int owner;
};
int main()
{
  Car c1,c3;
  Car c2=c1;//error
  c3=c1;//error 

}
```

Similarly ,when you will try to inherit this class , derived class will inherit the trait of being noncopyable as below

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Car {
public:
  Car(const Car&) = delete;
  void operator=(const Car&) = delete;
  Car(): owner(0) {}
  void setOwner() { owner = 0; }

private:
 int owner;
};
class myCar:public Car{};
int main()
{
  myCar c1,c3;
  myCar c2=c1;//Error
  c3=c1;//Error

}
```

Below error :

```
 In function 'int main()':
19:12: error: use of deleted function 'myCar::myCar(const myCar&)'
15:7: note: 'myCar::myCar(const myCar&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
15:7: error: use of deleted function 'Car::Car(const Car&)'
7:3: note: declared here
```